# ASP.NET MVC application throws error referencing assembly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc application that I needed to make a change on.   I made the change and now when I build it I get the message that says

**Could not load file or assembly 'Rotativa.MVC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)**

The change had nothing to do with the Rotativa and I did not touch anything on the code that used the Rotativa nor did I do any updates to the nuget packages.

This has been working for months so why now does it say the assembly is not signed?   and more importantly how do I correct this ?

Comment: Most probably you signed one of top-level assemblies of your app. Thus, all lower-level assemblies have also be signed. Inspect all projects of your solution and make sure they are not strongly signed (properties/signing).

Comment: As far as I remember if your project is signed it also requires all the referenced assemblies to be signed as well.

Comment: Thanks   In looking at the code somewhere along the line i did sign it.   I added the StrongNamer from nuGet to strongly name the referenced assemblies.